# DLL error in various GDAL installations

Tags: python

I have a couple virtual machines with Python (2.7.16 and 3.6.6 - 64 bit) with GDAL installed using GIS internals installers and using this process

However when running gdalinfo --version on the shell, in both I get an error:

```
C:\Users\K>gdalinfo --version
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll
126: No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files (x86)\GDAL\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll
126: No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.

GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20


C:\Users\K>gdalinfo --version
ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll
126: No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.

ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL: C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdalplugins\ogr_MSSQLSpatial.dll
126: No se puede encontrar el m¾dulo especificado.

GDAL 2.4.0, released 2018/12/14
```

The dll is located in the gdalplugins folder. Why does it fail in both installations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear from an old bug that it might be related to the MsSQL driver not being installed. [One commenter](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6589#comment:5) says that you can fix that by deleting (or renaming) that file to disable the plugin.